# How to generate waterfall steps at runtime in Bot Framework C#?

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework, chatbot

I have a Chat Bot made from Bot Framework v4 where I am reading Bot Response and Question that he wants to ask to a user.

This is one separate file:

**BotQuestions.cs**

```
 public class BotQuestions{

    public string Intro = "Welcome to Chat Session! I am Mr. A, your assistant.";

    public string AskFood = "How was your experience with our food?";

    public string Acknowledge = "I am glad that you liked our food!";

    public string Sad = "We apologize that you didn't enjoy our food. We will take care of it next time";
 }
```

And then I am calling this class in my Bot class where the WaterFall steps are defined.

**ChatBotDialog.cs**

```
public class ChatBotDialog : CancelAndHelpDialog
{

   public static BotQuestions question = new BotQuestions();

   public ChatBotDialog(UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState) : 

   base(nameof(ChatBotDialog))
   {
       memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();

       _conversationState = conversationState;

       // the waterfall method to maintain the order of the chat
       var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
       {
           IntroStepAsync,
           AskFoodStepAsync,
           AckStepAsync,
           SadAsync
       }; 

    // adding named dialogs to the Dialog Set. These names are saved in dialog set
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
    AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));


    // run the initial child dialog
    InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
   }

  private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> IntroStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(stepContext.Context.Activity.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);


        //BotReplyTime();
        var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(questions.Intro) // here I am accessing the Bot Question class string property and its value.
        };
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);

     }


private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskFoodStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
  // similar logic
 }


private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> AcknowledgeStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
  // similar logic
}


private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SadStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
  // similar logic
  }
 }
```

As you can see, the **ChatBotDialog** has waterfall steps and each step is calling **BotQuestions** class to access the string value.

**Now the situation is** if I want to add a new question in *BotQuestions.cs*, I have to generate the string value again, generate that corresponding waterfall step and then run the dialog which seems very clumsy... So is there a way to generate waterfall steps dynamically in runtime?? (**Only in C#**) If I add a new question anywhere in between **BotQuestions.cs**, is there a way that a bot can detect the change and adjust it accordingly? Is this possible?

Comment: I have a similar question posted at [multiple-waterfall-conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267723/multiple-waterfall-conversation-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Please let me know how you solved your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add waterfall steps dynamically.

It took a second to understand what you were doing. I don't suggest you build your waterfall based on a series of questions to the user, build it based on expected user input (ie "I need my user's shoes size, address and date of birth").

I would  recommend you look into the new [Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer). It is a UI-based, bot creation tool that builds bots around dialogs (not unlike what you're doing).

[image: composer image]